# Saving a separate record when saving the current record

Tags: ms-access

In my MS Access application the user opens the database to enter research notes (RNs). Each RN record needs to be attached to a project. All research notes entered during the current session relate to a specific project, which the user nominates on the first form. However, the RN - Project relationship is many-to-many. Although a single Project is attached when the RN record is created, other projects can be related later.

So... when I create and save a new RN record, I want to create a join table record with the new RN ID and the ID of the selected Project. I cannot find a way of creating this second record when creating the RN record. Does anyone have a way?  Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'cannot find' - what have you tried? Why not have VBA execute an INSERT action SQL? Why not use form/subform arrangement?

Answer (score 0):

As June7th implied, It doesn't sound like you have ruled out the normal access forms/subforms approach.  create a new database then insert the tables behind your many to many relationship.  Then go to the database tools tab and tell access about the many to many relationship.  For instance:
[image]

next select either of your main forms and then on the create tab select form and access will use the information about the relationships to auto-generate a rather ugly but working form and subform:[image]

Form Prettification is Recommended before giving to actual users.  Play around with the circled record selectors and try entering some data.  Then check the tables and you will see that they have been properly updated.  This approach may not work for your particular case, but try it because it is the easiest and fastest approach.  Next approach is to add a button which associates a note and a project then runs some vba to add them to the junction table between notes and projects.